# React Native WatermelonDB Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, watermelondb

So I installed WatermelonDB for React Native and wanted to use it. I did everything exactly like in the installation guide but it seems like it didn't work.

This is the error I get:
[image]

This are my dependecies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.1.5",
    "@nozbe/watermelondb": "^0.24.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.15",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.8.5",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "audit": "^0.0.6",
    "fix": "^0.0.6",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.8",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.2",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.30.1",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-pinchable": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-typing-animation": "^0.1.7",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
```

It does not matter if I try it with or without JSI. Does not work all the time.
I also use kotlinVersion = '1.4.21'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs are actually wrong. For everybody having the same problem:

index.js

```
...
myScheme,
...
```

has to become

```
scheme: myScheme,
```